# compare two columns in a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot

I've got a data set in an Excel Pivot table:

ID    **Owner**    Member

1     **Bob**      kelly
               jeff
               Bob

2     **Chris**    Jim
               Sally

sorry about the formatting, I bolded the owner

I want to do a filter where I can see only the IDs where the Owner is not in the Member list for each ID. so for the example, I only want to see ID 2 where Chris is not a member

Anyone know if I can do this in a pivot?

Comment: Please clarify how your data is arranged. Does cell C2 say "Kelly Jeff Bob", or does cell C2 say "Kelly", cell D2 says "Jeff", and cell E2 say "Bob?

Comment: C2 Kelly D2 Jeff E2 Bob

Answer (score 0):

Insert a new column A; this will be your filter column.

In cell A2, and dragged down, type:

```
=Iserror(search(B2,C2&D2&E2))
```

This searches for B2 within all of cells C2, D2, and E2 combined. If you ever have more than 3 names, you will need to also &F2 etc.

If it searches for B2 within the other cells and finds a match, it will return the letter where the word in B2 first appears. Otherwise it returns an error. So if there is an Error, ISERROR will return TRUE. Then just filter on column A for any TRUE rows.

**EDIT**

Alternative method, especially if there are often a changing number of people in the group.

Insert a new row to the left of A, as above. In A2, and dragged down, type:

```
=iserror(Match(B2,C2:Z2,0))
```

This works exactly as above, except that instead of searching for a word WITHIN a single string of text (like search), Match searches to see if any a given cell exactly matches any other cell in a range. This will only work if formatting of names is the same throughout.

Let me know if this doesn't quite suit your needs.

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping to a way to dynamically identify errors within an ever changing Pivot table. to reformat the formula would be harder than my manual process

Comment: You don't need to reformat every time. Assume that there are never more than 5 members. Just do as above, for 5 columns, and it will always pick up the correct data. If more than that, or if the number is ever changing - see my soon-to-be alternative method above.